# Change color for water region geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopandas

I want set sea area to water color, here is my code:

```
#@title Province plot

provinces['color'] = '#6b8e23'  # Default color for all provinces

# Plot the provinces
#'#6b8e23' land color
#'#a0cfff' sea color
provinces.plot(color='#6b8e23', linewidth=0.5, edgecolor='black', facecolor='#a0cfff')

# Set the title of the plot
plt.title('Map of Indonesia Provinces')

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

facecolor args doesn't work for me. Any idea how do I do it?

`provinces` is `GeoDataFrame` object.

Answer (score 0):

To use edge color needs to be passed in th dictionary missing keywords.

```
    provinces.plot(color='#6b8e23',
                   linewidth=0.5, 
                   edgecolor='black', 
                   missing_kwds= {facecolor='#a0cfff'})
```

Another thread:[use Geopandas plot missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58014486/use-geopandas-plot-missing-values)